# Is $(a \bmod N) \equiv (a \bmod x) \times (a \bmod y) $ where $x,y$ prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Can we say that for an $N$ where $N = xy$ and $x,y$ are prime
$$(a \bmod N) \equiv (a \bmod x) \times (a \bmod y) ?$$

Comment: No. $10 \mod 35 \ne (10 \mod 5) \times (10 \mod 7)$

Comment: counter example where $a$ is not congruent to 0 mod either $x$ or $y$  : use vvgiri's example, with $a = 2$ instead of $a = 10$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align} {\rm Hint\!:}\,\ \ \overbrace{(a+xj)}^{\large a_x}\overbrace{(a+yk)}^{\large a_y} &\,=\, a(a+\color{#c00}{xj+yk}) + xyjk\\[.2em]
&\,\equiv\, a\,\color{#0a0}{\Bbb Z}\!\!\!\pmod{\!xy},\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{x\Bbb Z+y\Bbb Z} = \color{#0a0}{\Bbb Z},\ \ {\rm by\ Bezout} \end{align}$
thus $\ \begin{align}a_x&\equiv a\!\!\!\pmod{\!x}\\ a_y&\equiv a\!\!\!\pmod{\!y}\end{align}\,\Rightarrow\ a_x a_y\,$ can be $\equiv \rm\color{#0a0}{any\ multiple}$ of $\,a,\,$ mod $xy$

Answer (score 0):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, the mapping $\Bbb Z_N\rightarrow\Bbb Z_x\times \Bbb Z_y$ given by $a\mod N\mapsto (a\bmod x,a\bmod y)$ is a ring isomorphism.

But your claim goes too far: $4\bmod 6 = (4\bmod 2)\cdot (4\bmod 3)$ amounts to $4 = 0\cdot 1$.